# How to trigger scroll event of a FlowLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, winforms

Here's my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

  public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      Button btn = new Button();
      btn.Text = "TEST";
      btn.Height = 35;

      this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn);
    }

    this.flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
    this.flowLayoutPanel1.Scroll += FlowLayoutPanel1_Scroll;
  }

  private void FlowLayoutPanel1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e) {
    MessageBox.Show("Event Triggered");
  }
}
```

And here's what the UI look like:

[image]

The scroll event just seems not be triggered while I scroll with mouse wheel inside the flowlayoutpanel

The solution shouldn't be hard to find, however I stuck on it for hours..
Can anyone point me some directions? Thanks!!

Comment: please post the code and not a picture of it. copy paste it into your post.

Comment: `flowLayoutPanel1.ScrollControlIntoView(btn);` or `flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(x, y);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a special [MouseWheel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.mousewheel?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) event that captures this

```
flowLayoutPanel1.MouseWheel += FlowLayoutPanel1_MouseWheel;

private void FlowLayoutPanel1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Scrolling Wheel");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for let me know how to ask the question properly & the great solution :)